# Java: bool + int

Tags: java

Is there a way to make Java work with boolean/integer addition and evaluation?
More specificly, C++ has an appropriate feature which shortens many if statements.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cout << i;
```

Is equivalent to

```
while (n--)
    cout << n;
```

Or, instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    if (x == y)
        count++;
```

One can have

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    count += (x==y);
```

Is there a way to do something similar to that in Java?

Comment: You know the terniary operator?

Comment: You can't use numbers as boolean values in Java, true and false are special values, they don't relate to numbers 0 or 1 (or any other non-zoro number). Also the two examples you provided in C++ seem to be really, really good examples of what not to do in terms of clean code.

Comment: @whatamidoingwithmylife I don't understand what is the "unclean" about `count += (x==y)` or `while (n--)`. Isn't it much more (1) readable, (2) elegant and (3) shorter?

Comment: @AvidSeeker it's not straightforward to understand for everyone, you are using language quirks in order to do something, it should be more expressive.

Comment: @AvidSeeker Polygnome basically told you the same thing in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ternary operator in Java for the same effect.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5, y = 10, count = 0;
        count += x == y ? 1 : 0;
        System.out.println(count);

        x = 10;
        count += x == y ? 1 : 0;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
```

Comment: This is not a bad workaround, but

(1) Is there a workaround for `while (n--)`
(2) I don't get it. How come a relatively low level language (C++) has such a simple feature (mere conversion between bool to int just like int + double = double) that Java doesn't have? (Isn't Java a higher level langauge than C++?)

Answer (score 0):

Code is more often read than written. While you can use the ternary operator, the *semantic* of this boils down to only *increasing `count` if `x` equals `y`*. So the most readable way to write this would be to use:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   if (x == y) count++;
```

Doing tricks like `count += (x==y)` in other languages is imho already bad practices since it obfuscates the logic. Optimize for reading, not writing.

Comment: also `while(n--)`.

Comment: Just like Java has the conversion `int + double = double`, why hasn't there been the simple elementary conversion `bool + int = int`?

Comment: @AvidSeeker Because double + int makes sense. Double models real numbers, int models whole numbers. Its reasonable to define `+` for both, since `ℤ` is a proper subset of ℝ. So in math, the addition operator for ℝ already includes whole numbers. It makes sense to preserve that property in computers. But booleans are completely disjunct from numbers. They have absolutely nothing to do with them, and are semantically totally different. Its coincidental that in some languages, booleans are represented by numbers. And imho its bad style to mix them in the way shown in the OP.